# Who is more likely to win the game?

Tags: probability, expectation

You meet your friend again, and this time she decides to play the following game with you.
She rolls 6n dice and wins if she gets at least n sixes. She offers you 6(n+1) dice, and declares
that you need at least n + 1 sixes to win. Who is more likely to win the game?

Comment: Does she roll first and win if she gets the $n\ 6$s regardless of what you do?  Do you each roll (assuming she fails) once and declare a draw if you both fail or do you keep rolling?

Comment: That is what I am also confused.

Comment: You need to get a clear statement of the rules.  Without that one cannot compute the chance of winning.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $X$ the number of sixes that appears in $6n$ rolls of your friend. And let $Y$ be the number of sixes in your first $6n$ rolls, and $Z$ be the number of sixes in your last $6$ rolls. Variables $X$ and $Y$ has the same distribution, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, and total number of sixes you get is $Y+Z$.

We need to compare two probabilities: 
$$
\mathbb P(X\geq n) \vee \mathbb P(Y+Z\geq n+1).
$$

We can replace $Y$ by $X$ in the second probability and deal with $\mathbb P(X+Z\geq n+1)$.

Simplify both probabilities: 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb P(X\geq n)=\mathbb P(X=n)+\color{red}{\mathbb P(X\geq n+1)}.
$$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X+Z\geq n+1) &=\color{red}{\mathbb P(X\geq n+1)}\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n, Z\geq 1)\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n-1, Z\geq 2)\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n-2, Z\geq 3)\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n-3, Z\geq 4)\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n-4, Z\geq 5)\ +\\ & \mathbb P(X = n-5, Z=6)\end{align}\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Two probabilities marked red are the same, and we need to compare the rest. Note that $X$ is the number of successes in $6n$ Bernoulli trials with success probability $1/6$, and $n=\lfloor(6n+1)\frac16\rfloor$ is the most probable number of successes. Therefore $\mathbb P(X = n-k) < \mathbb P(X = n)$ for any integer $k\geq 1$ and 
$$
\mathbb P(X = n-1, Z\geq 2) = \mathbb P(X = n-1) \mathbb P(Z\geq 2) <\mathbb P(X = n) \mathbb P(Z\geq 2),
$$
$$
\mathbb P(X = n-2, Z\geq 3) = \mathbb P(X = n-2) \mathbb P(Z\geq 3) <\mathbb P(X = n) \mathbb P(Z\geq 3),
$$
and the same is valid for all black summands in (\ref{2}).

We have: 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X+Z\geq n+1) & < \color{red}{\mathbb P(X\geq n+1)}\ + \cr & \mathbb P(X=n)\bigl( \mathbb P(Z\geq 1)+ \mathbb P(Z\geq 2)+\ldots +\mathbb P(Z=6)\bigr)= \cr & \color{red}{\mathbb P(X\geq n+1)} + \mathbb P(X=n) = \mathbb P(X\geq n) \end{align} \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
The sum in (\ref{3}) disappears since it is equal to 1:
$$
\mathbb P(Z\geq 1)+ \mathbb P(Z\geq 2)+\ldots +\mathbb P(Z=6) = \mathbb EZ = 1.
$$

Conclude that your friend is more likely to win the game.